# What kind of identifier should go in a RESTful URL

Tags: rest

In a typical case we include an identifier like so:

`/myService/products/1234`

And if I wanted to get the products for a given customer we'd do this:

`/myService/customer/999/products`

BUT, what if I wanted to get the products for a given customer and I don't model customers in my system? My system just store customer ID's on products. Would the above still be valid? You would get a 404 from `/myService/customer/` or `/myService/customer/999`

Would this be acceptable?

`/myService/products/customer/999`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "ReSTful URI". In ReST, you *follow* links given to you by the application. It is irrelevant how URIs look like, since you simply follow the ones given to you. If your application is ReSTful, it doesn't matter what the URIs look like. If it matters, what the URIs look like, your application isn't ReSTful. [Note: there may be *other* reasons for making URIs look a certain way, but they have nothing to do with ReST.]

Comment: `there may be other reasons for making URIs look a certain way,` As is mentioned in the RFC,  it's just a human concern. We make them "expressive" or "readable" for us to remember them well. Indeed, as Jorg W Mittag has commented, the URI could be something like `/myservice/?q=adas34asdak-342daasd234-234324324a-asdad` and still be REST :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the VoiceOfUnreason's answer (which I agreed with).

> what if I wanted to get the products for a given customer and I don't
> model customers in my system?

If we consider the mentioned [RFC 3986 - Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) and the fact that *customers* are not part of the model (hence, neither part of the API), probably the following URIs
are more appropiate

```
/myservice/products/?q=customer:12345
/myservice/products/?customer=12345
```

According to the question, `customers` seem to be only an attribute (`product.customer`). With no hierarchy. So, why to express hierarchy where there's not?

Any URI is going to fine anyways. URIs have nothing to do with REST. They are expected to be meaningless since the only readers are other applications (mostly, HTTP clients). Just remember what URI means (Uniform resource **identifier**).<sup>1</sup>

#### Considerations

If you foresee the possibility to implement `customers` in a near future, could be good not to use `/customer` any place (yet) since the representation of the resources referenced by these paths might change. Causing possible breaking changes to the clients. This is guesswork of course, but worth nothing to be aware of the possibilities for your API to change.

Web APIs can be really resilient when we adhere to all the principles of REST, but my experience tells me that this's not the case in most of the APIs out there. When we don't fully embrace REST (specially HATEOAS), API consumers use to be fairly coupled to the URIs and data models. In such cases, web APIs and changes don't get along.

---

<sup>1: The two alternatives suggested just try to fulfil the necessity of "expressiveness" (what OP is looking for) and convey with the common practices of web API designs. None of both required by REST.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for the URI; any information encoded into the identifier is done at the server's discretion and for its own exclusive use.

> Would this be acceptable? `/myService/products/customer/999`

Yup, that's fine.

Some might argue that it is semantically incorrect - [RFC 3986: Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form

The "/" literal is used to separate the segments in the hierarchy; so your spelling hints at the idea that "customer" is subordinate to products in the hierarchy, which probably doesn't make sense semantically.

It's closely analogous to creating a "customer" directory under the "products" directory in your file system.

As far as a URI parser is concerned, the spelling `/myService/products/customer/999` is perfectly fine.  But a human being familiar with the meanings of `products` and `customer` might be surprised by the implied subordinate relationship.

Is there value in choosing a less surprising spelling?  Perhaps.